How to call an Azure function from ADF and pass parameters to the function
I have an Azure function written in Python. This function takes DatabaseName, CompanyId, TeamId and AssessmentId as parameters. I need to call this Azure function from ADF. I'm using the Azure function activity in ADF to call this function and passing the parameters using pipeline parameters. I tried multiple ways and everything resulted in the below error -
Call to provided Azure function 'textgenerationtrigger?DatabaseName=devenv&CompanyId=123&TeamId=456&AssessmentId=789' failed with status-'NotFound' while invoking 'POST' on 'https://fun-cus-textprep-dev.azurewebsites.net' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - NotFound.'.
I tried testing the function endpoint on Postman and it ran successfully. Query used -
POST request: https://fun-cus-textprep-dev.azurewebsites.net/textgenerationtrigger?DatabaseName=devenv&CompanyId=123&TeamId=456&AssessmentId=789
Steps taken to call my Azure function from ADF:

Used the Azure function activity
Linked service pointing to the Azure function app is created and selected as a linked service
Function name: (tried two ways)

a. textgenerationtrigger (Just the function name)

 b. textgenerationtrigger ?DatabaseName=@{toLower(pipeline().parameters.DatabaseName)}&CompanyId=@{pipeline().parameters.CompanyId}&TeamId=@{pipeline().parameters.TeamId}&AssessmentId=@{pipeline().parameters.AssessmentId} (function name with query parameters)


Method: Post
Body: (tried two ways)

   a. {
   "DatabaseName": "@{pipeline().parameters.DatabaseName}",
   "CompanyId": "@{pipeline().parameters.CompanyId}",
   "TeamId": "@{pipeline().parameters.TeamId}",
   "AssessmentId": "@{pipeline().parameters.AssessmentId}"
   } (when using just the function name in function name section)

   b. {} (When using function name with query parameters)

The expected outcome is Azure function endpoint being executed successfully in the same way on how it is being successful when pinging via Postman.

Since this function is running successfully in postman and not running in ADF, the issue is in the azure function linked service configuration with ADF.
If the Azure Function app is using anonymous authentication or function-level authentication, you can specify the function app name only in the linked service and include the function name and query parameters in the Azure Function activity in ADF itself..


While creating linked service, give only the https://<fun-name>.azurewebsites.net in the function URL. Do not copy the entire function URL and paste.



Paste the value after code= from the function URL( as shown in above image)   in the function key text box of linked service.



Then create the linked service and in azure function activity, give the proper function name and along with the dynamic query params as you have done

<function-name>?DatabaseName=@{toLower(pipeline().parameters.DatabaseName)}&CompanyId=@{pipeline().parameters.CompanyId}&TeamId=@{pipeline().parameters.TeamId}&AssessmentId=@{pipeline().parameters.AssessmentId}


Set the method to "POST".

Leave the body with empty Json, since the query parameters are being passed in the URL.



With this configuration, the Azure Function activity in ADF should be able to call the Azure Function app.

Here, in init.py I have just taken those values and printed and sent as response of function app:
import logging as ri
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    ri.info('Hello Bojja')
    test = req.params.get('tst')
    ting = req.params.get('ting')
    jing = req.params.get('jing')
    test = f"First Param is {test}, Second Param is {ting}, Third Param is{jing}" 
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello Rithwik, {test}")

Calling Function:
In Function Name in adf use :
HttpTrigger1?tst=rithwik&ting=bojja&jing=chotu send parameters directly.

HttpTrigger1 is function name.
Output:

Alternatively if you want to use url parameters:
Here, I have used route in In function.json as below where i have given like test/{test}/{ting}/{jing}:
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "test/{test}/{ting}/{jing}",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}

Here, in init.py I have just taken those values and printed and sent as response of function app:
import logging as ri
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    ri.info('Hello Bojja')
    test = req.route_params.get('test')
    ting = req.route_params.get('ting')
    jing = req.route_params.get('jing')
    test = f"First Param is {test}, Second Param is {ting}, Third Param is{jing}" 
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello Rithwik, {test}")

Calling Function:
In Function Name in adf use :
test/rithwik/bojja/chotu send parameters directly.

Output:

So, make changes in function.json and use the cotrrect url to call it. My function name is Httptrigger1 but you need not use that when you are using route as above.
